# JQuery Slide (this) element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get this working where if you hover on the div with the class of photo, the photo-info slides in for that div (not both). I think I need the 'this' in Jquery but I am a little lost. I don't want to have to give each div.photo a separate id. How can I amend my script?

```
                  <div class="photo">
                      <div class="photo-info"><p>Some information</p></div>                   
                  </div>
                  <div class="photo">
                      <div class="photo-info"><p>Some information</p></div>                   
                  </div>
```

.photo-info {display:none;}

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".photo").hover(function () {
    $(".photo-info").slideToggle("slow");
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this here you can get the children of that div

```
$(this).children(".photo-info").slideToggle("slow");
```

Comment: Vitorino your are a genius. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".photo").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".photo-info").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this` selector and `find` to make sure you are only accessing that element's children like here:

```
    $(".photo").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".photo-info").slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/91dbvu72/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what you want you indeed will need to use the `this` but don't be scared. It is actually very straightforward. Take a look at this snippet:

```
    $(".photo").hover(function () {
    $(".photo-info").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Just use this instead:

```
$(this).children(".photo-info").slideToggle("slow");
```

And all problems solved. Hope this helps.